# Correct MVC-compatible way to populate QComboBox as a QTableView delegate

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, delegates, qtableview, qcombobox

I have been following the Qt QSpinBox delegate [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html) to make a QComboBox editor delegate in a QTableView cell. I was able implement the editor and populate the combobox with items from an external source ('dictionary') by using a private data member of the delegate class:

delegate.h

```
class Delegate : public QItemDelegate
{    
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Delegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    //...

    void setDictionary(const QStringList &dict);
    void setCurrIndex(const qint16 &ind);

    //...

private:
    // the internal dictionary, wich is being filled from an external source
    QStringList dictionary;
    int currentIndex;
};
```

delegate.cpp

```
//...
QWidget *Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);

    editor->clear();
    editor->addItems(dictionary);

    return editor;
}

void Delegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QComboBox *cbox = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
    QString str = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
    int idx = dictionary.indexOf(str);
    cbox->setCurrentIndex(idx);
}

    void Delegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QComboBox *cbox = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
    QString val = cbox->currentText();
    model->setData(index, QVariant(val), Qt::EditRole);
}

void Delegate::setDictionary(const QStringList &dict)
{
    dictionary = dict;
}

void Delegate::setCurrIndex(const qint16 &ind)
{
    currentIndex = ind;
}
```

Populating the internal dictionary with a defined external source in a window method:

```
QStringList dict;
// ...    
// filling the dict with strings
// ...
mydelegate = new Delegate(this);
mydelegate->setDictionary(dict);
```

Is this solution MVC-compatible? If not, then how do I write a 'correct' MVC-styled method of providing the data to delegates like these?

Comment: And how do you implement [`setModelData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#setModelData)? Do you translate `QString`s from the dictionary back to your model?

Comment: @Mike, being new to Qt, I am just reproducing the setModelData() implementation from the mentioned example, adapting it to a combobox editor. That is, I'm taking current text from the combobox and sending it into the model data: `QString val = cbox->currentText();` `model->setData(index, QVariant(val), Qt::EditRole);`. Therefore, I have my model linked with the editor through the cell data, which is QString, without involvement of combobox's currentIndex. Edit: added the `setModelData()` impementation to the question.